# Combine multiple exchange mailboxes in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

I have a user that has 5 different Exchange email accounts from 5 different domains.  He wants me to combine all 5 accounts so they show up in 1 account, meaning when he clicks on Inbox it shows all of his mail from all accounts.  He is using office 2016, any ideas or products that would resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for sounds like an "Inbox All" or "Unified Mailbox" approach. This can be done via an Macro as Outlook out of the box didn´t support that.

You can check our this [Tutorial here for Outlook 2013](https://www.slipstick.com/how-to-outlook/how-to-create-a-unified-inbox/#comment-172511).

P.S. As this require multiple steps i will only post an link/URL here as I do not really wish to "steal" a whole website to post it here.